# Changing the fonts of address-bar & search engines in Firefox3.6?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I have Firefox 3.6
My screen resolution is 1920*1200 (120 DPI), hence the fonts of Firefox address-bar and Firefox Search Engines are too small.
Can we change the fonts of them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go into `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile-name]\chrome` (replace profile-name with whatever it mentions in that particular folder)
2. Edit the `userChrome.css` file in WordPad and add this to the bottom:

   ```
   /* Make my URL bar and Search bar bigger and bolder. Now dammit. */
   #urlbar, #searchbar .searchbar-textbox{
   font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 16pt }
   ```

   Change 16pt and Arial to whatever size and font that you want.
3. Restart Firefox, voila, URL bar *and* Search bar font is now bigger.

*Source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=244616*

Comment: No such file in Firefox 23

Comment: @Laserson create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I had to do 2 more things for this to work. 1) enable `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` on the "about:config" page and 2) add `!important` to the css value, as in `font-size: 14pt !important;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the Firefox GUI in the userChrome.css file in your Firefox user profile directory. More details [here](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss).

You'll need something like the following to change the font size in the location bar:
`#urlbar {
    font-size: 30px;
}`