# In Chrome in Windows 10, how do I change the font used in the URL bar to be more secure?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, fonts, phishing

The same text in Chrome's URL bar in Windows 7 and in Windows 10:

[image]

As seen above, Windows 7 shows an uppercase `i` with **Serifs**, making it easily distinguishable from a lowercase `L`; but Windows 10 displays the two characters roughly the same.

This is a security problem since it makes it more difficult to spot phishing URLs.

(This also appears to be present in Firefox, but that browser has a more accessible option to change fonts.)

Comment: Relevant: [Changing the fonts of address-bar & search engines in Firefox3.6?](http://superuser.com/q/111298)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the fonts of address-bar & search engines in Firefox3.6?](http://superuser.com/questions/111298/changing-the-fonts-of-address-bar-search-engines-in-firefox3-6)